# Take different row of same group based on different data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df1) containing different word labels (ia_label) in the same participant/sentence group (ID2), and we have a label for each word label in each participant/sentence group (ID_IA).

```
df1 <- structure(list(
  ID2= c("1_1", "1_1", "1_1", "1_1", "1_1", "2_1", "2_1", "2_1", "2_1", "2_1", "3_1", "3_1", "3_1", "3_1", "3_1", "1_2", 
         "1_2", "1_2", "1_2", "1_2", "2_2", "2_2", "2_2", "2_2", "2_2", "3_2", "3_2", "3_2", "3_2", "3_2"), 
  ia_label = c("The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5","The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5", "The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5", "The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5","The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5", "The_TW1", "cow_TW2", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5"),
ID_IA = c("1_1_The_TW1", "1_1_cow_TW2", "1_1_jumped_TW3", "1_1_the_TW4", "1_1_gate_TW5", "2_1_The_TW1", "2_1_cow_TW2", "2_1_jumped_TW3", "2_1_the_TW4", "2_1_gate_TW5", "3_1_The_TW1", "3_1_cow_TW2", "3_1_jumped_TW3", "3_1_the_TW4", "3_1_gate_TW5", "1_2_The_TW1", "1_2_cow_TW2", "1_2_jumped_TW3", "1_2_the_TW4", "1_2_gate_TW5","2_2_The_TW1", "2_2_cow_TW2", "2_2_jumped_TW3", "2_2_the_TW4", "2_2_gate_TW5", "3_2_The_TW1", "3_2_cow_TW2", "3_2_jumped_TW3", "3_2_the_TW4", "3_2_gate_TW5")),
  .Names = c("ID2","ia_label", "ID_IA"),
  row.names = c(NA, -30L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

I also have a different data set (df2) containing only one row/one ID_IA from each participant/sentence group.

```
 df2 <- structure(list(
  ID2= c("1_1", "2_1", "3_1", "1_2", "2_2", "3_2"), 
  ia_label = c("cow_TW2", "the_TW4", "jumped_TW3", "the_TW4", "The_TW1", "jumped_TW3"),
  ID_IA = c("1_1_cow_TW2", "2_1_the_TW4", "3_1_jumped_TW3", "1_2_the_TW4","2_2_The_TW1", "3_2_jumped_TW3")),
  .Names = c("ID2","ia_label", "ID_IA"),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a new data frame (df3) which takes from df1 only the row AFTER those included in df2

```
df3 <- structure(list(
  ID2= c("1_1", "2_1", "3_1", "1_2", "2_2", "3_2"), 
  ia_label = c("jumped_TW3", "gate_TW5", "the_TW4", "gate_TW5", "cow_TW2", "the_TW4"),
ID_IA = c("1_1_jumped_TW3", "2_1_gate_TW5", "3_1_the_TW4", "1_2_gate_TW5","2_2_cow_TW2", "3_2_the_TW4")),
  .Names = c("ID2","ia_label", "ID_IA"),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

So essentially I want to take the ID_IA's in df2 and use these to then take the [ID_IA's + 1] in df1 to create df3.

Would this be a case of creating a vector containing all of the ID_IA's in df1 and then using filter (plus an additional command to take the next row after that ID_IA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to join the two data.frames by all columns. An indicator could be added to the second data.frame, so that when joined, would indicate rows that matched. Then, you can `filter` where the previous row was matched.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2$keep <- TRUE

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  filter(lag(keep)) %>%
  select(-keep)
```

**Output**

```
  ID2   ia_label          ID_IA
1 1_1 jumped_TW3 1_1_jumped_TW3
2 2_1   gate_TW5   2_1_gate_TW5
3 3_1    the_TW4    3_1_the_TW4
4 1_2   gate_TW5   1_2_gate_TW5
5 2_2    cow_TW2    2_2_cow_TW2
6 3_2    the_TW4    3_2_the_TW4
```